# Angular 1.5 Non-Parent Component to Component Communication

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to do something simple.

I have a component called sender that wants to send a message to a non-child component called receiver.   Sender finds the receiver component and changes its attribute value.

Unfortunately, the receiver component doesn't recognize that it's attribute has been changed.

When this is done, there will be multiple sending components that will make use of the same receiving component instance, so I don't want to make it a child component.

How do I get the receiving component to recognize it has a new attribute value?

Here's a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/M5g8Ao)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8"  
            src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test sending values to a component from a non-parent component</h1>
    <sender id="SendingComponent"></sender>
    <h2>past send tag</h2>
    <receiver id="ToComponent"  textvalue="defaultvalue"></receiver>
    <h2>Past receiver tag</h2>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[])
  .component("sender", {
    template: "<div> I send messages to receiver.  
       Receiver should say 'a new sent value'.</div>",
    controller: [function () {
      var ctrl = this;
      ctrl.$oninit = function () {
      var receiver = document.getElementById('ToComponent');
        receiver.attributes.setNamedItem('textvalue', 'a new sent value');
      $timeout(function () { $scope.apply();});
    };
  }]})
  .component("receiver", {
    template: '<div>I received this message: 
      {{receiverCtrl.textvalue}}</div>',
    bindings: {
      textvalue: '<'  // using '@' makes the default value work, 
                      // but is described as a one time bind
    },
    controllerAs: 'receiverCtrl',
    controller: [function () {
      var ctrl = this;
      ctrl.$onChanges = function (changesObj) {
        if (changesObj.textvalue !== undefined) {
          ctrl.textvalue = changesObj.textvalue.currentValue;
        }
      }
    }]
});

angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like you should be working with events instead. Maybe your senders would [$broadcast](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast) the value to be changed, and your receiver would listen to that event and do whatever needs to be done with the value.

This also has the advantage of your senders not needing to manipulate the DOM to send their message. This way, you'd leave DOM manipulation to the receiver only, if necessary.

Comment: That solved the problem.   I chose $rootscope.$broadcast due to where the components might be in the fully implemented version.

While reading up on this topic, I found a reference to this github code, which might be more efficient (per the original comment I tracked it down from).  Haven't verified it, but here's the link: https://github.com/georapbox/angular-PubSub